# How to get current time in Swift?

Tags: swift, date, nsdate

I'm trying to get the current time, and I've done this so far:

```
    let date = NSDate()
    let calender = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calender.component([.Hour, .Minute], fromDate: date)
```

And I then try to get the hour of the components

```
    let hour = components.hour
```

This give me *"Value of type "Int" has no member 'hour'"*. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
let components = calender.component([.Hour, .Minute], fromDate: date)
```

to

```
let components = calender.components([.Hour, .Minute], fromDate: date)
```

Answer (score 4):

`NSCalendar.component(_:fromDate:)` returns a *single* component of a date, as an `Int`. So your `components` variable is actually of type `Int`. Passing multiple units to `component(_:fromDate:)` (as you are doing) is undefined.

Try this instead:

```
let components = calender.components([.Hour, .Minute], fromDate: date)
```

Note that the first part of the method name here is `components`, not `component`.

Also, you might want to change your `calender` variable to `calendar`, since that is the correct spelling.

Answer (score 1):

swift 4

```
let hh2 = (Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date()))
let mm2 = (Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: Date()))
let ss2 = (Calendar.current.component(.second, from: Date()))

print(hh2,":", mm2,":", ss2) 

 output: ---> 9 : 10 : 55
```